# Error when adding scriban template to rendering variant migrated from 9.1.1 to 10.2

Tags: sxa, scriban

I'm currently in the process of upgrading our solution from Sitecore 9.1.1 to 10.2.  Our solution has a number of nVelocity templates that I need to replace with scriban templates.  I've also already run the SXA upgrade steps for 9.1.1 to 10.2.

Whenever I add a scriban template item to a rendering variant, I'm getting the following error.

```
Method 'TryGetItem' in type 'Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Scriban.ContextExtensions.ItemAccessor' from assembly 'Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Scriban, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
```

Has anyone run into this issue before?

[image]

Comment: can you add your scriban script ? did you try to add just a simple html without taking any values from fields to see if is crashing?

Comment: Yes, I added a scriban template with just the word "test" in there.  As long as a scriban template is added to the rendering variant, it crashes.

Comment: can you compare your dlls with a clean 10.2 solution with sxa . I search for the trygetitem method in that assembly in 10.2 and doesn't exist. I guess you have a mix of old solution dll and new solution.

Comment: Good point!  I'll take a look.

Comment: So, I think maybe this Scriban dll from Nuget has an issue?  The TryGetItem is defined from the Interface IObjectAccessor which is not implemented in Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Scriban.ContextExtensions.ItemAccessor

Comment: Are you using Scriban 3.6 version?

Comment: @VladIobagiu Eureka!  That was it!  2 of the projects in the solution had nuget packages with 5.4.4!  They're all at 3.6 now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add correct reference to Scriban.dll .
Sitecore 10.2 works with version 3.6 of Scriban.

[image]